# HowTo get the previous element from std::deque?

Tags: deque

For example I have an array with about 10 elements in it.

```
std::deque<int> d;
front_inserter(d) = 100;
front_inserter(d) = 200;
front_inserter(d) = 300;
...
front_inserter(d) = 900;
front_inserter(d) = 1000;
```

**Question**: how to find `900` element, **without** using `[]` access? If the size of the massive will be changes, for example to 123, how to find 122 element?

PS: I don't want to use `[]` because this method does not perform `d[-1]` check...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use deque::at.

`d.at(121)`

Comment: You are saying to check like this? - `d.at(d.size() - 1)`?

Comment: Yes. And in case d.size() == 0 there must be an exception

Comment: I resolved this solution with the other way, not using STL, but with help of program logic. Any way thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a runtime check throwing in case of out of bound access you can use ::at(pos).
If you mean d[-1] being the last element, d[-2] the second-last and so on (a-la Python) then you've to code your own (possibly template) function for that.

Comment: No, I need a method to get `second-last` element from deque-array which could be with the different size...